# Falsy zero should pass

Tags: javascript

I pass a value as parameter to a function. The value can come either as `obj.value` or `obj.val`. I use this shorthand to determine what to select:

```
fn(obj.value || obj.val)
```

The problem is that when the value is `0`, the shorthand breaks, because zero is falsy. What would be the simplest way to pass zero when it arrives?

Thank you

Comment: Should your `fn` accept only `Number` values? If yes - I use `!isNaN(val)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
fn(obj.value !== undefined ? obj.value : obj.val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this `fn(obj.value || obj.val || 0)`